# How can I change a h1 element of another html page?

Tags: javascript, html, session-storage

I am trying to use sessionstorage to bring an input name from index.html into the heading1 of start.html.

Is this possible?

Comment: If you want to take the value input and set it in start.html, yes

Answer (score 0):

Yes, first set the value. Then just have an if statement check to see if the current page is start.html.

```
//setting in index.html
sessionStorage["test"] = 1;

//getting for start.html
if(location.href.indexOf("start.html") > 1){
   console.log(sessionStorage["test"])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

```
document.getElementById("myh1").textContent = sessionStorage.getItem("myinput");
```

Or whatever variable names you have stored. Note that you need to call this function after the h1 is loaded in the dom which means if there is text inside it will show as one thing then flash to another.